# Creating a server on python

Tags: python, sockets, server, raspberry-pi

I’m trying to create a server on my raspberry pi using python and then i want to test the server by accessing it from another device using the IP address of the raspberry pi, but the problem is that everytime i type the IP address of my raspberry pi into my webpage, it doesn’t open and i don’t know if there’s a problem in my code or not, i will write below so that anyone could check

```
import socket    
import sys

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()

try:
    my_socket.bind((host, 1234))
except socket.error:
    print(‘failed’)   
    sys.exit()

my_socket.listen(5)

While True:
    conn, addr = my_socket.accept() 
    data = conn.recv(1000)
   
    if data:
        print(‘got a request’)
        my_socket.send(‘Thank you’)
   
my_socket.close()
conn.close()
```

after that i tried typing the raspberry pi’s IP address on my laptop’s webpage but it was no use, first i typed ifconfig in the terminal of the raspberry pi to get the IP address and i tried it but it didn’t work, then i added another line in the code which is gethostbyname to the variable host and printed it and it showed different  IP address than the one in ifconfig which was confusing to me, but i even tried this another IP address on my webpage and it didn’t work too

Comment: There is at least one problem in your code: `while` needs to be spelled with a lower-case w.

Comment: Why is your code double-spaced

Comment: `python3 -m http.server` from the command line will start up a simple server than you should be able to access from any device on the network.

Comment: Make sure you post the *exact* source code, unless you actually have smart quotes in your file in which case that's a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check with netstat to see if the code is actually listening? Should list the <IP>:<Port> as LISTENING, i always check that when i do server code.

Sometimes when you try out code and don't terminate it properly, there can be a orphan process still listening to the Interface:Port hogging the port. Been there, done that, got the T-shirt.

Also, try using 0.0.0.0 instead, it tells the socket listener to listen on all interfaces, including loopback.

Got any firewall denying the connection ? Check that.

Also, check try using curl as a debug tool and see if 1) Curl can connect and 2) you get send some HTTP data to the server:

```
Curl 127.0.0.1:1234/HelloWorld
```